# When is the quotient of an algebra by a polynomial algebra a free module?

Tags: abstract-algebra, symmetric-polynomials, free-modules

Let $A$ be a $k$-algebra and let $V$ be a subalgebra of $A$ that is a polynomial algebra.  Is $A$ a free module over $V$?

One example is when $A=\mathbb{C}[x_1, x_2, \ldots x_n]$ and $V$ is the ring of symmetric polynomials in $n$ variables.  Can you prove that $A$ is free over $V$?

Comment: For your specific example, $A$ is free of rank $n!$ over $V$. It is proved here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/216242/free-kx-1-dots-x-ns-n-module/216253#216253.

Comment: Thanks! That's a nice clean proof.